# Publishing a file to multiple servers simultaneously

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration

Below is my requirement:

```
Make changes to a file --> Commit the change to git --> The tool should track the commit and publish the changed file from the git repo to multiple servers automatically.
```

Is there a tool that meets the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, however generally git does have built-in support for executing commands when changes are committed or pushed. Please read about [git hooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

Specifically you will want to look at the `post-update` hook which is intended for notifications (in your case notifying or publishing to the other “servers”):

> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which happens when a git push is done on a local repository. It executes on the remote repository once after all the refs have been updated.
>   It takes a variable number of parameters, each of which is the name of ref that was actually updated.
>   This hook is meant primarily for notification …